# List All Pages of Parent Page

Tags: wordpress, parent-child

I am trying to figure out how to list all child pages of a parent page in WordPress in a custom sidebar widget. I have written a very simple plugin that allows me to do the exact same thing with categories that looks like this:

```
query_posts("category_name=$category&showposts=$show_limit");
if (have_posts()):
    echo "<ul>";
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>"><i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i></a>
        <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile;
    echo "</ul>";
endif; ?>
```

In the above example, `$category` and `$show_limit` are set on the Appearance > Widgets screen in the WordPress back end.

Is it possible to do the same thing for a page that has multiple child pages? For example, if there parent page were named `Services`, how would I list all the child pages in a similar fashion to the above approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly important, *don't use* `query_posts`:
[**When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)

You can use the function [`get_page_by_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title), and do something like (not tested):

```
$services = get_page_by_title( 'Services' );

if ( is_page( $services->ID ) )
{
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type'   => 'page',
        'post_parent' => $services->ID,
    );
    $subpages = get_posts( $args );
    if( $subpages )
    {
        foreach( $subpages as $page )
        {
            echo $page->post_title;
        }
    }
}
```

Check the full list of parameters to use in `get_posts()` at the Codex: [Class_Reference/WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).